# how correctly infer types in ramda pipe fn

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I try to start using ramda for extracting data[].data.tags but typescript show type error

```
  R.pipe(
    R.map(R.prop('data')),
    R.map(R.prop('tags'))  // typescript error
  )([{data: {tags: ['t1', 't2'], title: ''}, meta: null}])
```

I think need to send type in R.pipe<T1, T2>, but I want that typescript to infer automatically these types

I use

```
    "@types/ramda": "^0.27.60",
    "typescript": "4.5.4",
    "ramda": "^0.27.1",
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Thank you for all your suggestions

Comment: I am not sure you will aim your target. This depends on the types that comes from Ramda and unless you want to patch them - you will have to live with that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found that [fp-ts-std](https://samhh.github.io/fp-ts-std/ramda) can match ramdas functional programming utilities for typescript. It has all the equivalent functions, curried and typed. With caveat of focusing on ADT.